# Getting Error When Getting TableViewCell IndexPath on OutSided Button

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am getting index and doing multiple selection check boxes but when I am doing without debug. It is crashing with this error  `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` And it is crashing particular 7 index if I am using iPhone XR Device. Just because UITableView is not scrolling . So, How can I do it without scrolling.

It is Crashing on this line `let cell = connectionTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) as! NotificationTableViewCell`

```
@IBAction func btnSelectAll(_ sender: Any) {
    let totalRows = connectionTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
    print(totalRows)
    for index in 0..<totalRows {
        print(index)
        connectionTableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)

        let cell = connectionTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) as! NotificationTableViewCell

        cell.btnCheck.isSelected = !cell.btnCheck.isSelected

        if cell.btnCheck.isSelected == false
        {
            arrayMultiple.remove(at: index)
            print(arrayMultiple)
            checkButton = false
        }
        else
        {
            let notificationDict = notificationArray[index ] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
            let notification_id =  notificationDict["_id"] as? String
            arrayMultiple.append(notification_id!)
            print(arrayMultiple)
            checkButton = true
        }

    }
}
```

I just want to select all check boxes on button click which is situated outside of TableView

Answer (score 0):

The code crashes because you are going to access cells which are not visible at the moment. `cellForRow(at` returns `nil` for an invisible cell.

Nevertheless your approach is cumbersome and error-prone.

- Use a struct rather than a dictionary as data source and add a member `isSelected`

  ```
  struct NotificationItem {
      let id : Int
      // other members
      var isSelected = false

  }

  var notificationArray = [NotificationItem]()
  ```
- Delete `arrayMultiple`.
- Map your array of dictionaries to the struct type.
- In `cellForRow` set the checkbox according to the value in the struct

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView, cellForRowAt....

      let item = notificationArray[indexPath.row]
      cell.btnCheck.isSelected = item.isSelected
  ...
  ```
- Now you can reduce the code in the `IBAction` to

  ```
  @IBAction func btnSelectAll(_ sender: Any) {
      notificationArray.forEach{ $0.isSelected = true }
      connectionTableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```

Comment: Not working . Getting crash on items in `CellforRow`

Comment: What is `items`?

Comment: it is the count of cells. But according to your way it is not getting any item